# Go_router and Sidebarx in flutter

Tags: flutter, sidebar, gorouter, flutter-go-router

I've tried to use [Sidebarx](https://pub.dev/packages/sidebarx) with web navigation, using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)
https://github.com/tas-unn/tttt
this is my project, which doesn't works correctly.
Full code you can see [here](https://github.com/tas-unn/tttt/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

1. When I first run the application and click on the menu items there, no errors occur. But when you click on the "dashboard" or "personal" buttons, a strange animation occurs and, judging by the print command, Hompage also starts. Although visually everything works.
2. When I reload the "dashboard" or "personal" page, a warning is displayed:
   `Could not navigate to initial route. The requested route name was: "/dashboard" There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.` But if I leave the switching example from the main example of [repository](https://pub.dev/packages/sidebarx/example) (_ScreensExample class), then the url of the webpage does not change.
   Tell me what I'm doing wrong!